# The proper way to compile SFML on vscode with G++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, sfml, vscode-tasks

I want to know which is the proper way to use and configure VSCode build tasks, using G++ and some libraries (in this case, SFML).

I'm using linux mint, when i type the build command directly on the terminal it works fine and compile the source.

I used 'sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev' to install sfml.
SFML is located at: '/usr/include/SFML/'.

[image: Terminal]

[image: SFML]

But when using the same build command (the same args) inside a vscode task.json, the compiler cannot include SFML/Graphics.hpp.

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "Build",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g", "${workspaceFolder}/source/Source.cpp", 
                "-o", "${workspaceFolder}/release/AppLx",
                "-lsfml-graphics", "-lsfml-window", "-lsfml-system", "-lm",
                "-I/usr/include/"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/release/"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/g++"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the build output:
[image: builderror]

(EDIT)
While trying to add the include to the intellisense, i saw that even the 'c_cpp_properties.json' can't locate the SFML, but as showed on the 2d image, the SFML folder exists.

VS version: 1.60.2 (Official package on Software Manager).
[image: vseerr]

Comment: intellisense and your compiler's include paths in 2 different files. I am not sure why it can't find your headers when building.

Comment: You don't need to add `-I/usr/include`, this path is default.

Comment: I know, but it's not finding SFML there anyway.

Comment: It looks like you have installed libsfml-dev and are running visual studio code on two different PCs.

Comment: What do you mean by using two computers? Yes, thats right, but on windows i used Visual studio, not code.
I'm porting from visual studio to vscode. I deleted all vstudio files and trying to create a build file only for vscode. (I'm intend to abandon vstudio)

Comment: As i'm having trouble with vscode build, i'm using a .sh file for build (but that's not practical)